# AngularJS ngInfiniteScroll keeps firing as I scroll up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

My upwards scrolling triggers my `infiniteSubjects()`. But it should only trigger it while scrolling downward. I've already looked into many posts but haven't figured out a solution. I've tried messing around with `infinite-scroll-disabled`. Also tried sticking a 1003px height `<div>` in different places at the bottom to take up space. No dice. :/

```
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="gridController" class="container">
    <div class="row" infinite-scroll="infiniteSubjects()" infinite-scroll-distance="0" >
        <div ng-repeat="subject in (filteredSubjects = (allSubjects | orderBy:subjectOrder | limitTo:subjectLimit))">

            <div class="col-md-2 subject-card">
                {{ subject.name }}
             ..more divs in here..
            </div>
        </div>
    <div style="clear:both; height:1003px;"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside my controller:

```
$scope.infiniteSubjects = function() {
    console.log("scrolling");
    $scope.subjectLimit += 1;
};
```

I've also gone inside `ng-infinite-scroll.js` file to see what the heights were as it was scrolling by adding some console.logs

```
windowBottom = $window.height() + $window.scrollTop();
console.log("WINDOWBOTTOM " + windowBottom);

elementBottom = elem.offset().top + elem.height();
console.log("ELEMENT BOTTOM" + elementBottom);

remaining = elementBottom - windowBottom;
console.log("REMAINING" + remaining);
```

When the page loads:

```
WINDOWBOTTOM 1194
ELEMENT BOTTOM 1194
REMAINING 0
```

I don't think window bottom and element bottom should be the same starting out. Why are they like this?

As I scroll down, my `remaining` will increment by `-100`
As I scroll up, my `remaining` will increment by `100`, but it never becomes positive since the page starts at 0

Answer (score 2):

After some more digging around SO, I came across another person's answer on a similar post:
[ngInfiniteScroll - loadMore() method gets called on every mouse-scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666712/nginfinitescroll-loadmore-method-gets-called-on-every-mouse-scroll#comment51376181_23786831)

All I needed to do was specify `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of my html.

Comment: Yes! It solved my problem! A whole 24-hours nightmares! Thanks!