# jquery window orientation change event not working in requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, requirejs

I have one problem when i use window orientation change event its not firing on devices. Here, i have added my code. Please help me out from this issue.

Example code,

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
    $(function() {
        set_screen();
    });

    function set_screen(){
        var winH = $(window).height(),
            winW = $(window).width();
        $('.fullscreen-slider ul.slide li').css({'height':winH});
    }

    $(window).on("orientationchange", function(event) {
        set_screen();
    });
});
```

Comment: Put an alert within `orientationchange ` and see if it appears.

Comment: its appearing. But I'm facing one problem, i can't get exact window height when i rotate the screen... @LShetty

Comment: You'd be better of with `height: 100%`

Comment: The problem is getting window height value.... @LShetty.

Answer (score 0):

This may explain why you are not getting the window height you expect, though we would need to see your HTML and CSS to be sure:

[jquery $(window).height() is returning the document height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103208/jquery-window-height-is-returning-the-document-height)

That said, as @LShetty pointed out in comments above, you can achieve the same result much more easily by simply giving the element a height of 100%.  Best to do this in a stylesheet file, but if you have to do it in Javascript:

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.fullscreen-slider ul.slide li').css({'height':'100%'});
    });
});
```

No `orientationchange` handler needed.

Comment: "When a number is passed as the value, **jQuery will convert it to a string and add px to the end of that string.** If the property requires units other than px, convert the value to a string and add the appropriate units before calling the method." (Documentation of [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/). Emphasis added.)

Comment: @Louis, thanks, didn't know that.  Will edit answer to reflect.

Comment: If i write like this, $(window).on("orientationchange", function(event) {alert($(window).height())}); i'm getting landscape view screen height value in portrait view. If i use requirejs i'm facing this issue... @phari