# django cms popup window height is too big

Tags: django-cms

I'm using DjnagoCMS 3 and I have annoying problem with all editing popup windows. It happens when page content is bigger (higher) than browser window. When I try to edit text or any cms plugins (double click on content) it shows popup window, but it's height is greather than height of monitor resolution.
[image: gray ractangle is popup window, but it's content is outside of browser window]

If content length is not so big, everything is ok.
[image: For small page popup window is ok]

Problem is somewhere in js/css of django cms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution. The problem is that this line:
https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/release/3.0.x/cms/static/cms/js/modules/cms.modal.js#L137
returns the content-height, not the window height, because of this:
[jquery $(window).height() is returning the document height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103208/jquery-window-height-is-returning-the-document-height)

So all you need to do to fix this is declare a doctype in your template.