# Why does min-height:100% not work since declaring a doctype?

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have a `div` with the class `.app`, which has the following css rules:

```
.app {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The `min-height` was working as expected, getting the app div to fill the screen even if it was empty - this is because the content is loaded via ajax and I want the div to reach to the bottom of the screen even before the content is loaded.

However, I'd previously forgotten to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to my document, and now that that's corrected, the height rule no longer works. The `doctype` has to be there, both because it's required and to solve [a jQuery issue I was having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103208/jquery-window-height-is-returning-the-document-height).

Why is the `doctype` messing with my css? Or, possibly more to the point, why was it working beforehand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you **remove the doctype** the browser goes into **quirks mode** which does things differently to help older code that is **not validated** to **render correctly**.

Because ancient browsers had odd, **inconsistent behavior** and browsers treat Doctypes like an intelligence test to see if the author is writing code to the standards or to what they learned from W3Schools a decade ago.

If you have **height: 100%** and the height of the **parent** element is **auto** then **100%** means **auto**.

Only if the **parent** element has a **defined height**, i.e not a value of **auto**. If that has **100% height**, the parent's parent height must be defined, too. This could go until to the html root element.

So set the **height** of the **html** and the **body** element to **100%**, as well as every single **ancestor element** of that element that you wish to have the **100% height** in the first place.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
}

#mydiv {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Well, your history in your second paragraph is not quite correct, and has more to do with Microsoft's failings in IE, so I'll refer you to this: https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `vh` unit, dependant on which browsers you need to support. So:

```
#mydiv {
    min-height: 100vh
}
```