# Stop moving div with page before footer

Tags: jquery, css, fixed

I am using this tutorial http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/ to make my div move with page while user scrolling. It works like a charm, but until you reach bottom of my web and div have still position fixed and still moving from his parental div to footer.
JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var top = $('#comment').offset().top - parseFloat($('#comment').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('#comment').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('#comment').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#comment.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Here is my page, so you can look what exactly is my problem:
http://testportal.jon.cz/projekt-konfigurator/konfig.html

Sorry for my english and thanks for your answers :)

Comment: can you post some code? Don't know how to fix something without seeing how it is built

Comment: Whole code what I use for it is in first link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it once using `css` property `transform` on [Cart Page](http://dev.cako.com/checkout/cart/index/). All you need to calculate the offset which you can do dynamically with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  offset = jQuery('fieldset').offset().top;  // offset from top of the left content
  fieldset = jQuery('fieldset').outerHeight();  // outer height of the left content
  collaterals = jQuery('.cart-collaterals').outerHeight();  // outer height of the movable right content
  maxTop = fieldset > collaterals ? (fieldset - collaterals) + offset : offset;
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    st = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (st > offset && st < maxTop) {

      jQuery('.cart-collaterals').css('transform', 'translate(0px, ' + (st - offset) + 'px)');
    } else if (st < offset) {
      jQuery('.cart-collaterals').css('transform', 'translate(0px, 0px)');
    } else if (st > maxTop) {
      jQuery('.cart-collaterals').css('transform', 'translate(0px, ' + (maxTop - offset) + 'px)');
    }
  });

});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var top = $('#pravyKonfig').offset().top - parseFloat($('#pravyKonfig').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var max = $('#odber').offset().top - $('#pravyKonfig').outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function(evt){
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('#pravyKonfig').removeClass('fixed');
        if(y > top && y < max){
            $('#pravyKonfig').css('transform', 'translate(0px, ' + (y - top) + 'px)');
        }else if(y < top){
            $('#pravyKonfig').css('transform', 'translate(0px, 0px)');
        }else if(y > max){
            $('#pravyKonfig').css('transform', 'translate(0px, ' + (max - top) + 'px)');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have absolutely not idea, how to adapt this for my code

Comment: @AdamVýborný: I've added the new code below **update**. Hope that will help you.

Comment: It is not that smooth, like with fixed position, but it works, like a charm! Many thanks for help!!!

Comment: @AdamVýborný: try removing `$('#pravyKonfig').removeClass('fixed');`. In my case it is smooth. may be some of css causing the problem.

Comment: Doesn't help... It is still blinking a little: http://testportal.jon.cz/projekt-konfigurator/konfig.html

Comment: I just checked it and the scroll is smooth. you may check for `var top`, it do have a `float` type value. try change it to `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the position from fixed to a new value or to recalculate the bottom value.

if you are using jQuery. Here is an exemple not the best one but from a project I just got. So not my code but working. Still you'll have to adapte for your purpose. But as you can see if the position of the scrollbar excede a certain value the position of the div is changed.

```
var menuPosYloc = parseInt($("#Header").css("top").substring(0, $("#Header").css("top").indexOf("px")))
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(e){
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > menuPosYloc ) {
                $("#Header").css({"position" : "fixed", "top" : "20px" });
            }
            else {
                $("#Header").css({"position" : "absolute", "top" : "20px; right:0px" });
            }
        });
```

You may need to see this link for a scrollBottom() function

[Opposite of "scrollTop" in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188903/opposite-of-scrolltop-in-jquery)