# How to get the amount of pixels scrolled down the page with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

Now I know I can use `scrollTop()`, but that gets me the amount of pixels from the top of the screen. Would it be possible to get the amount of `px` from the bottom part of the screen to top?

Answer (score 2):

Just assign a variable to a function with the properties similar to scrollTop (but opposite) like this:

```
$.fn.scrollBottom = function() { 
  return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height(); 
};
```

Then just call it as follows:

```
$(window).scrollBottom();  //how many pixels below current view
$("#elem").scrollBottom(); //how many pixels below element
```

Via- [Opposite of "scrollTop" in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188903/opposite-of-scrolltop-in-jquery)